# Add Google Earth imagery to Google Earth Engine project

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have the following code:

```
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
  .filterDate('2018-03-15', '2018-09-15')
  .filterMetadata('MGRS_TILE','equals','34TFM')
  .filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Point(23.20, 41.88))
  //.filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Point(pin))



function addImage(image) { // display each image in collection
  var id = image.id
  var image = ee.Image(image.id)
  print(image)
  Map.addLayer(image, {bands: ['B8', 'B11', 'B4'], max: 5000}, 'S2')
}

s2.evaluate(function(s2) {  // use map on client-side
  s2.features.map(addImage)

})
```

To download a collection of Sentinel-2 images to a location in my project. However, I would like to add Google Earth imagery into my project. Is it possible?

Comment: No problem! consider clicking the green check mark to mark this as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click the "satellite" tab next to the "layers" bar to view the google satellite imagery with your project:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. Google Earth's imagery is not currently available anywhere other than via the Google Earth application.